# cloudant docker developer edition issue with replicate

Tags: docker, couchdb, cloudant

We have a local dev edition running locally in a stock docker image, all is well and good.

We cannot get test items re: replication (even internally from 1 db to another inside docker image or further to cloudant.com to replicate).

I am aware the image license is for a single non cluster node, but is there a way to push docs etc from a local dev db to cloudant.com db on a one time push?  Or test replication development locally? (ie 2 dbs inside docker image)

Essentially does "non-clusterable" = no one way, one time, push replication?  Even internally inside the image from 1 db to another db in the same docker image?

Here is info re: image-  https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/cloudant-developer/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on the exact issue you are seeing, but replication should work when running Cloudant inside Docker. You just need to understand how to route to your Cloudant instance.

I noticed that when I create a new local replication in the Cloudant Dashboard it uses the port that is in the Cloudant Dashboard URL which is the port mapped in Docker. For example, I map port 80 to 30080. When I try to replicate from database test1 to a new database called test2 it creates a replication from localhost:30080/test1 to localhost:30080/test2. This will not work because the Cloudant instance thinks everything is running on port 80 not port 30080.

So, my work around was to tell the Cloudant dashboard to do a remote replication, but specify localhost/test1 (equivalent to localhost:80/test1) to localhost/test2. See the screenshot below:

[image]